# Eclipse randomly replaces characters with \uFFFD in properties file

Tags: eclipse, character-encoding

In one of my properties file, which is UTF-8 encoded, Eclipse randomly replaces accentuated characters with "\uFFFD".

I say randomly because it does not do so on all of accentuated characters, just some of them, when I save the file. And it is not always the same ones :)

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: What properties file? Are you editing the file using the Eclipse properties editor? Properties files are normally ISO-8859-1 encoded.

Comment: This is a property file I created myself. I am using the "JBoss Tools Properties Editor" to open it, maybe that's the problem. My properties file have the right encoding in the Eclipse parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Until the problem reappears, I declare this to be the solution: using "Properties File Editor" to open properties file, and not "JBoss Tools Properties Editor".